# The trackpad click is unresponsive after screen unlock on MacOS Catalina on MacBook Pro 2018

Tags: catalina, trackpad, magic-trackpad, click

I upgraded my MacOS from High Sierra to Catalina and now I find that after screen unlock, the trackpad click becomes unresponsive. I have to go to desktop (dragging three fingers up) and select a window (of any app) to make the trackpad click responsive again. I didn't have this issue on MacOS High Sierra. Please help in resolving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening due to the Right Zoom application running in the background. Once I removed that application from the login items, the issue got resolved.

Comment: Did you have `Right Zoom` installed on `High Sierra`?

Comment: @dan yes, I had.

Answer (score 1):

ajay.

Do you already have the latest version (10.15.4)? If not, try to update, if yes, try the following:

1) [Reset your Mac's NVRAM or PRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063).

2) If you continuing experiences issues, try to [reset the SMC of your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295).

I hope that works.

Comment: I already have 10.15.4 and I tried both but to no avail. The issue is still there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue. What I've noticed is that the system looks for a wireless bluetooth mouse. After the timeout the trackpad starts working.